# How to insert FavIcons to SharePoint list from different websites?

Tags: javascript, powershell

as you can probably read from the title, I want to populate a column in my SharePoint list with favicons from different websites depending on the url in the corresponding field entry.

I would use PowerShell or JavaScript, but have completely no idea of how to approach this problem the best?
Do you have any tips for me?

Comment: Is the iconurl a field value in the current list?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated column with the following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE("<img src='http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain="&[you-url-column]&"'/>")
```

Comment: note the **&** itself is a string concatenation, so you do not require the outer ``CONCATENATE( )``